# Review data section at end of long form (Blazor html)?

Tags: html, forms, blazor

I have several long form sections in a Blazor html project. After a user has completed all of the fields, I would like there to be a section at the very end where they can double-check the data they have inputted before submitting. Can anyone give me the basic structure/advice of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isFilled` `->` is just a variable to hold the current state.

```
@if(isFilled == false){
       
       <<<<<<Here is the data entery>>>>>>>>

       <button @OnClick="next">Next</button>

}


@if(isFilled == true){
    <section>
       
       <<<<<<<<<<<Review the data here>>>>>>>>>

       <button @OnClick="confirm">Confirm</button>
       <button @OnClick="edit">Edit</button>

    </section>

}
```

Code section :

```
 @Code{
      private bool isFilled;
    
      protected override void OnInitialized()
      {
        isFilled = false;
      }
      

      private void next(){
        isFilled = ture;
      }

      private void edit(){
        isFilled = false;
      }
      private void confirm(){
        
      }
    }
```

Comment: Really great, high-quality answer. Thanks, they're rare